# Magento Cash on Delivery Extra Fee

Tags: magento, payment

There are many questions asked revolving around this same topic but none could provide a concrete answer. Basically what I am looking for is adding a certain constant fee if cash on delivery payment method is selected.
I could have easily done it with a ready-made extensions(many free alternatives available) but I don't want to use any extensions. I want to code this thing.

Can anybody give me a proper guidance. To start with I have basic experience of magento modules, Hello World types of modules.